# Electron pair operators and anticommutation relations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, education, anticommutator

Fermions creation and annihilation operators obey the anti-commutation relations given by:

$$ \{ c_{\bf{k} \sigma} , c^{+}_{\bf{k'} \sigma'} \} = \delta_{\bf{k}\bf{k'}}\delta_{\sigma\sigma'} 
\\
\{ c_{\bf{k} \sigma} , c_{\bf{k'} \sigma'} \} =
\{ c^{+}_{\bf{k} \sigma} , c^{+}_{\bf{k'} \sigma'} \} = 0 $$

where $\sigma = \uparrow \downarrow$ denotes spin states.

We can also write the operators in real space, by a Fourier transformation:

$$ \hat{\psi}_{\sigma} ( {\bf r} ) =
\frac{1}{V^{1/2}} \sum e^{i {\bf k} \cdot {\bf r} } 
\ c_{{\bf k}\sigma}
\sim \frac{1}{V^{1/2}} \int e^{i {\bf k} \cdot {\bf r} } 
\ c_{{\bf k}\sigma} \ d^{3}k $$

which leads to the relations:

$$ \{ \hat\psi_{\sigma}({\bf r}), \hat\psi^{+}_{\sigma'}({\bf r'}) \} = 
\delta({\bf r} - {\bf r'}) \delta_{\sigma\sigma'} 
\\
\{ \hat\psi_{\sigma}({\bf r}) , \hat\psi_{\sigma'}({\bf r'}) \} =
\{ \hat\psi^{+}_{\sigma}({\bf r}) , \hat\psi^{+}_{\sigma'}({\bf r'}) \} = 0 $$

My question is: how can one perform this procedure?
Would it be something like this:

$$ \{ \hat\psi_{\sigma}({\bf r}), \hat\psi^{+}_{\sigma'}({\bf r'}) \} = \bigg\{ \frac{1}{V^{1/2}} \sum_{k} e^{i {\bf k} \cdot {\bf r} } 
\ c_{{\bf k}\sigma} \ , 
\frac{1}{V^{1/2}} \sum_{k'} e^{-i {\bf k'} \cdot \ {\bf r'} } 
\ c^{+}_{\bf{k'} \sigma'} \bigg\} = 
\\
\frac{1}{V} \sum_{k} \sum_{k'} e^{i {\bf k} \cdot {\bf r} } \ e^{-i {\bf k'} \cdot \ {\bf r'} } 
\ \{ c_{\bf{k} \sigma} , c^{+}_{\bf{k'} \sigma'} \}
=
\\
\frac{1}{V} \sum_{k} \sum_{k'} e^{i {\bf k} \cdot {\bf r} } \ e^{-i {\bf k'} \cdot \ {\bf r'} } 
\ \delta_{\bf{k}\bf{k'}}\delta_{\sigma\sigma'} 
=
\\
\frac{1}{V} \sum_{k} e^{i {\bf k} \cdot ({\bf r} - {\bf r}^{'}) }
\delta_{\sigma\sigma^{'}}
=
\delta({\bf r} - {\bf r}^{'}) \ \delta_{\sigma\sigma^{'}}
$$

Moreover, if we have electron pair operators, such that:

$$
\hat{\varphi}^{+}({\bf R}) = \int \varphi ({\bf r})
\ \psi^{+}_{\uparrow} \big( {\bf R + \frac{r}{2}} \big)
\ \psi^{+}_{\downarrow} \big( {\bf R - \frac{r}{2}} \big)
\ d^{3}r 
$$

where ${\bf R}=(1/2)({\bf r_{1}+r_{2}})$ and ${\bf r}={\bf r_{2}-r_{1}}$, are the center of mass location and distance between the electrons, respectively; Can the commutation relation:

$$
[\hat{\varphi}({\bf R}),\hat{\varphi}^{+}({\bf R}^{'})]
$$

be determine in the same fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I agree with how you went from the Fourier space to real space commutation relations, I will apply the same steps to the electron pair operator you defined.
\begin{align}
[\hat{\varphi}(R), \hat{\varphi}^+(R^\prime)] &= \int \int d^3 r d^3 r^\prime \varphi(r) \varphi^*(r^\prime) [\psi_{\downarrow}(R - r/2)\psi_{\uparrow}(R + r/2), \psi^+_{\uparrow}(R^\prime + r^\prime / 2) \psi^+_{\downarrow}(R^\prime - r^\prime / 2)] \\
&= \int \int d^3 r d^3 r^\prime \varphi(r) \varphi^*(r^\prime) \left [ \psi_\downarrow(R - r/2)\{\psi_{\uparrow}(R + r/2), \psi^+_{\uparrow}(R^\prime + r^\prime / 2)\}\psi^+_\downarrow(R^\prime - r^\prime/2) - \psi_\downarrow(R-r/2)\psi^+_\uparrow(R^\prime+r^\prime / 2)\{\psi_\uparrow(R + r/2), \psi^+_\downarrow(R^\prime - r^\prime / 2)\} + \{ \psi_\downarrow(R-r/2), \psi^+_\uparrow(R^\prime+r^\prime / 2) \} \psi^+_\downarrow(R^\prime - r^\prime / 2)\psi_\uparrow(R + r/2)  - \psi^+_\uparrow(R^\prime + r^\prime / 2) \{ \psi_\downarrow(R-r/2), \psi^+_\downarrow(R^\prime - r^\prime / 2) \} \psi_\uparrow(R+r/2)\right ].
\end{align}
Now two terms vanish and the other two give
\begin{align}
\int d^3 r \left [ \varphi(r) \varphi^*(2R - 2R^\prime + r) \psi_\downarrow(R - r/2)\psi^+_\downarrow(2R^\prime - R - r/2) - \varphi(r)\varphi^*(2R^\prime - 2R + r) \psi^+_\uparrow(2R^\prime - R + r/2) \psi_\uparrow(R + r/2) \right ].
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: how can one perform this procedure? Would it be something like this:

Yes that is a legitimate way to do it.

> Can the commutation relation:
> [̂ (),̂ +(′)]
> be determine in the same fashion?

Calculating commutation relations is always the same: $\{A, B\}=AB+BA$ and you carry out the calculations.